# Cannot resolve method 'getCurrentList' in 'FirebaseRecyclerOptions'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am working on a college search app and I am unable to solve this error.

Here is the code:

```
public class searchEngineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String stateSelected;
    public String courseSelected;
    public RecyclerView searchRecyclerView;
    public WebView webView;
    public FirebaseRecyclerOptions adapter;
    public DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String queryState, queryCourse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_engine);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        stateSelected = bundle.getString("stateSelected");
        courseSelected = bundle.getString("courseSelected");
        Log.e("arguments",stateSelected+courseSelected );
        makeQuery(stateSelected, courseSelected);
        searchRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.searchRecyclerView);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        searchRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        setAdapter();
        searchRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL));
    }

    public void makeQuery(String q, String c) {
        queryState = q.replaceAll(" ", "-");
        queryState = queryState.toLowerCase();
        queryCourse = c.toLowerCase();

    }

    public void setAdapter() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("searchengines");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<searchModelClass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<searchModelClass>().setQuery(query, searchModelClass.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<searchModelClass, androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(options) {

            //@Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull searchRecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull searchModelClass model) {
                holder.setSiteImage(model.getImage());
                holder.setSiteName(model.getName());
                holder.setSiteURL(model.getUrl());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@androidx.annotation.NonNull @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @androidx.annotation.NonNull @NonNull searchModelClass model) {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@androidx.annotation.NonNull @NonNull LoadingState state) {
            }

            @NonNull
            //@Override
            public searchRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.search_recycler_view, parent, false);

                final searchRecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new searchRecyclerViewHolder(view);
                viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new searchRecyclerViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                        **databaseReference = adapter.getCurrentList(position);**
                        databaseReference = databaseReference.child(queryCourse);
                        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String queryURL = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                queryURL = queryURL.replaceAll("state", queryState);
                                webView.loadUrl(queryURL);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
        searchRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<Object, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = null;
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    } //UPDATING RECYCLER VIEW REGULARLY FROM THE START OF FRAGMENT
}
```

Error is:

> Cannot resolve method 'getCurrentList' in 'FirebaseRecyclerOptions':101

I tried to use other library for recycler view in place of firebase ui library, but then I have to change my whole code. What else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `adapter` object is an object of type `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter`. When you try to call `getCurrentList(position)` on such an object, it's the expected behavior to get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getCurrentList' in 'FirebaseRecyclerOptions':101
```

Since there is no `getCurrentList()` method inside your adapter class. Moreover, if such a method existed, as the name says, it would have returned a list and not a `DatabaseReference` object. So seeing your code, that line of code that produces that error should be removed.

Comment: If I remove that line of code new error appears. i got error in line 72 stating: 'FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter(com.firebase.ui.database.paging.DatabasePagingOptions<com.example.shubhamr.collegesearch.RecyclerViews.searchRecylerView.searchModelClass>)' in 'com.firebase.ui.database.paging.FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter' cannot be applied to '(com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions<com.example.shubhamr.collegesearch.RecyclerViews.searchRecylerView.searchModelClass>)' . What should I do now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot debug your entire code. So you have to step through the debugger and see why you have that new error. Or, you can post a new question, here on StackOverflow using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey, abhay. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: I tried using your answer, but a new error keeps occurring that I am unable to resolve.

Comment: Have you tried Frank's solution? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `getRef()`? That'd be:

```
databaseReference = adapter.getRef(position);
```

I highly recommend keeping the source code for the class you're using handy in cases like this, as the entire [`FirebaseAdapter.java` file](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseAdapter.java) is only 47 lines long and can quickly help you find what *does* and what *doesn't* exist.